# Error-The variable must be numeric in cocor

Tags: r

I ran a simple function cocor for the difference in correlation, but I got the error message: one of the variables (temporality) must be numeric. So I checked the data type of the variable and it is double/numeric. I do not have the issue to calculate partial correlation or confidence interval using the same database.

```
cocor(~temporality+expectability|temporality+positive,data =data2)
is.numeric(data2$temporality) # True
```

Data2 is a database with 5 variables (gender and 4 numeric measures).

So what is the real reason behind the issue? Thank you

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(data2)`?

Comment: it is too long to be displayed here. it shows all column details: 1 binary variable - gender and 4 numeric variables. At the end of the result, there is extra info: row.names = c(NA, -199L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")).

Comment: By chance, did you read the data in with the haven package?

Comment: No, the data comes from excel csv.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with "The variable 'x' must be numeric." for the cocor function. I found somewhere that cocor does not seem to work with tibbles, but when the data is converted to data.frame it works.

Your script would go like this:

```
cocor(~temporality+expectability|temporality+positive, data = as.data.frame(data2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Saved me a lot of headaches....

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used **cocor.indep.groups** and **cocor.dep.groups.overlap** to deal with numeric issues.